# Taking mysql data backup with php5

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I am using php5 and mysql5.- in my local server

1. I want to take mysql database backup ( in my local server ) - just by copying the
   datafile ( located in mysql server in the folder data )
2. I have copied a particular table name account.frm file - but it is not working 
   It is showing the table name  but it is showing error that ( I checked in the mysql
   query browser )
   that cannot fetch the table details.
3. I have used mysqldump it is also not working.

Please help me to take backup and work correctly.

Comment: Including in your question what you've tried and in what ways that doesn't work will help people tell you what will work. For example, you say you've used mysqldump and that it is not working. mysqldump should work fine, therefore you're probably not calling mysqldump correctly. Show us what doesn't work and we can make small changes to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I use PHP to create compressed MySQL dumps daily. If using PHP under Linux, a generic representation of what you need is:

```
exec('mysqldump -u [username] --password=[password] [databaseName] > [sqlDumpFilename] ');
exec('tar cvzf [compressedFilename] [sqlDumpFilename]');
```

This will result in [compressedFilename] containing a compressed MySQL dump to use as you need. Skip the compression step if not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried backuping your database with phpmyadmin http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php ?

you should have phpmyadmin installed, - if you installed localserver bundle, but if not take a look at this php function for backuping database :

```
function backup_tables($tables = '*')
{
// the $db var is connection to your database!
     global $db;

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++)
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    //save file
        // specifiy the path where you want to backup the file...
    $filess = 'db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql';
    $handle = fopen($filess,'w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);
    return $filess;
}
```

the function will create INSERT INTO instructions in .sql file, which then can be used for import into newly created database.